# Is it possible to make query result in running another query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
$aircraft_query = "SELECT COUNT(aircraft) as total, aircraft FROM db_pireps WHERE pilotid = $pilotid GROUP BY aircraft ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 6";
$planes = DB::get_results($aircraft_query);
```

And using a foreach statement, I can generate rows in a table to show aircrafts flown by a `pilotid`. However, I'd like now the `RESULT` to link to another table and extract data from there, such as aircraft type, in a `fullname` column.

I have this: `<?php echo $aircraft->fullname; ?>` but that data is in a different table. So, if `aircraft` was 30, it would access 30th record in `db_aircrafts` table and take the `fullname` column. How can I do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: You mean with SQL joins?

Comment: Yes, that's what I understand too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is called a table [`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) (also see [JOIN in MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(a.aircraft) as total
    , a.aircraft
    , b.fullname AS aircraft_name
FROM db_pireps AS a
JOIN db_aircraft AS b
    ON a.aircraft = b.id
WHERE pilotid = {$pilotid}
GROUP BY aircraft 
ORDER BY total DESC 
LIMIT 6
```

Comment: The result is still as before. Only the total of `aircraft` in `db_pireps` is displayed. Three records are displayed, because for my `pilotid` there are three "PIREPs" (Pilot Reports), so three `aircraft` were used.

Comment: Excuse me, it was just me being a bit blind, all I needed to do was to change `fullname` to `aircraft_name` in the echo. Thank you!

Comment: Just one more thing, how would I call `registration` into the query from the database to use in an echo? `<?php echo $aircraft->registration; ?>` returns `unexpected $end` error.

Comment: @zzwyb89 you need to include this field in the `SELECT` clause so it is returned from the database. Maybe it's time for you to learn a bit more SQL using tutorials to understand those things better?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I'll take a look at some tutorials, is there any you'd recommend?

Answer (score 1):

You should use SQL Joins.

```
SELECT COUNT(A.aircraft) as total, A.aircraft, B.fullname
 FROM db_pireps A
 LEFT JOIN pilot_data_table B ON A.pilotid = B.id
 WHERE A.pilotid = $pilotid
 GROUP BY A.aircraft ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 6
```

Comment: It throws out a `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. The foreach is: `foreach($planes as $aircraft)`

Comment: That means the query failed. You should never execute a foreach without checking that you really have an array. Did you replace the parts on the query I wrote to you, with the columns you have on your tables?

Comment: It would help if you show me the exact columns of both tables.